# Is the Traveler the same entity in all timelines?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Is The Traveler Capable of time travel? And if so are they the same entity no matter what timeline you are in? 
Or are they limited to a specific timeline?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking here; can you provide a little more context and better explain your question?

Comment: I only recall the traveler being in one episode of TNG. Was he in any other episodes or movies or other media? I wonder if the lack of response to this question may be due to the traveler not having been in much star trek media. Perhaps the OP should document where he has seen mention of the traveler so that the question can be more clearly framed.

Comment: He was in three episodes, in fact: Where No One Has Gone Before, Remember Me, and Journey's End. Additionally, he's appeared in some short stories, but I'm not sure on the policy here with Star Trek EU, so I wouldn't cite those.

Comment: Perhaps Memory Beta may contain relevant citations, as it did for @Olivee_C's answer to this [other question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4137/what-happens-to-wesley-crusher-when-he-leaves-with-the-traveler#).

Comment: Excellent question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Traveler is indeed capable of time travel, or at least, what the Traveller does is, from his point of view, equivalent with time travel in a human perspective:

> RIKER: You are from a different time, aren't you?
> TRAVELER: Well,
> no, not exactly from another time. Although as you understand the
> concept, yes, perhaps that term fits as well as any.
> [s1e06 Where No One Has Gone Before](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/106.htm)

When they are at the edge of reality, Picard also seems to feel that they have travelled through time as well as space:

> Captain's log. Any time entry is meaningless.
> [s1e06 Where No One Has Gone Before](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/106.htm)

Additionally, the Traveler's abilities manipulate energy *and* time via thought:

> TRAVELER: Such musical genius I saw in one of your ship's libraries. One called Mozart, who as a small child wrote astonishing symphonies. A genius who made music not only to be heard, but seen and felt beyond the understanding, the ability of others. Wesley is such a person. Not with music, but with the equally lovely intricacies of time, energy, propulsion. and the instruments of this vessel which allow all that to be played. You're right, I must hurry now. But you're right in something else. He is just a boy for now. He should be encouraged, but told none of this.
>
> ...
>
> TRAVELER: I have the ability to act like a lens which focuses thought.
> [s1e06 Where No One Has Gone Before](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/106.htm)

However, as an entity, he does seem to be bound to a singular timeline. In the tremendously existentially terrifying episode "Remember Me", when Beverly is trapped in an alternate reality, the Traveler helps Wesley rescue her. They use specifically Starfleet means of manipulating warpfields to rescue her, and the Traveler never hops over to her reality to explain what's going on. Of course, Wesley uses his latent Traveler powers to be able to find the right alignment and "see beyond the numbers", but this doesn't imply that he could, of his own volition, skip between dimensions.

For less canon sources, I recommend "Gods, Fate, and Fractals" by William Leisner, in which Wesley screws up the time stream by removing the Maquis from reality, and the Traveler promises to fix the problem.

Comment: Outstanding answer, thank you very much. This answers my question perfectly.